# What is the error and what is indented block?

Tags: python, indentation

## when I run the program below

```
from sys import argv
# this one is like your scripts with argv

def print_two(*args):
arg1=args,
arg2 = args,
print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % arg1, % arg2

# ok, that *args is actually pointless, we can just do this
def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2)

# this just takes one argument
def print_one(arg1):
print "arg1: %r" % arg1s

# this one takes no arguments
def print_none():
print "I got nothing."

print_two("Zed","Shaw")
print_two_again("Zed","Shaw")
print_one("First!")
print_none()
```

## Output:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
PS C:\Users\user> python F:\software\Python\ex18.py   
File "F:\software\Python\ex18.py", line 4     
arg1,arg2 = args       
^
```

Comment: indentation matters in python, you know...

Comment: You need to indent function body using a consistent number of spaces. (eg shift every line by 4 spaces). May I ask where are you learning Python from?

Comment: The reported error line `arg1,arg2 = args` does not exist in the code posted.  But there are indeed indentation errors to be fixed as the answers suggest.

Comment: @RaviKumar, it looks like he's learning from [LPTHW](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex18.html)

Answer (score 3):

In Python, indentation is significant. You should take a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), more specifically  the indentation part. And remember: if your code isn't indented, it's not a valid Python code.

According to [this Python 3 tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php):

> A block is a group of statements in a program or script. Usually it consists of at least one statement and of declarations for the block, depending on the programming or scripting language.
>
> A language, which allows grouping with blocks, is called a block structured language. Generally, blocks can contain blocks as well, so we get a nested block structure.
>
> A block in a script or program functions as a mean to group statements to be treated as if they were one statement. In many cases, it also serves as a way to limit the lexical scope of variables and functions.
>
> [image]

So, you code should work fine if you indent it correctly:

```
from sys import argv
# this one is like your scripts with argv

def print_two(*args):
    arg1=args,
    arg2 = args,
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % arg1, % arg2

# ok, that *args is actually pointless, we can just do this
def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2)

# this just takes one argument
def print_one(arg1):
    print "arg1: %r" % arg1s

# this one takes no arguments
def print_none():
    print "I got nothing."

print_two("Zed","Shaw")
print_two_again("Zed","Shaw")
print_one("First!")
print_none()
```

Comment: You might want to add a citation and some block quotes so that you aren't plagiarizing.

Comment: Quoting content is fine, but **you must provide attribution**. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not indented properly. the error says clearly.

1) you have to indent your code.
Python strictly follow indentation.

2) in line 7 your code `arg1` , `arg2` should be reformatted.

3) in `print_one` function `arg1` should be printed, not `arg1s`.

You could run your code as follows.

```
from sys import argv
# this one is like your scripts with argv

def print_two(*args):
    arg1=args,
    arg2 = args,
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2)

# ok, that *args is actually pointless, we can just do this
def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2)

# this just takes one argument
def print_one(arg1):
    print "arg1: %r" % arg1

# this one takes no arguments
def print_none():
    print "I got nothing."

print_two("Zed","Shaw")
print_two_again("Zed","Shaw")
print_one("First!")
print_none()
```